# Base64 value causing StringBuilder.append out of memory error in SAX parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, base64, stringbuilder, saxparser

I am using SAX parser to parse the XML file which is the response from client's server.  tag has inside the Base64 decoded value of the files (jpg, png, pdf etc.). Some of them I can easily write to file but with some of them (I am guessing the large one) I have a problem during StringBuilder.append on the overwritten method of DefaultHandler:

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (valueActive) { // set to true only when <value> tag is active
        stringBuilder.append(ch, start, length); // OUT OF MEMORY error
    }
}
```

On the next steps, I am using Base64Encoder to write files:

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {

        valueActive = false;

        try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(my file here)) {

        base64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringBuilder.toString());

        stream.write(base64);
   } catch .... / omitted part of code
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve out of memory issue? Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)
        at com....AttachmentHandler.characters(AttachmentHandler.java:47)
```

EDIT:

Base64 is from XML:

```
<value> String encoded with base64 </value>
```

For SAX parser I am using RestTemplate:

```
@Override
@Retryable
public Application performMultimediaRequest(String url) {

    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();

        restTemplate.execute(url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                responseExtractor -> {
                    try {
                        saxParser.parse(responseExtractor.getBody(), attachmentHandler);
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        log.error("Cannot parse API response with SAX parser");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
        );
    } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
        log.error("Cannot parse response with SAX parser");
    }

    return attachmentHandler.getApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either increase the JVM heap memory to accommodate `StringBuilder` memory requirements or use [`Base64.getDecorder().wrap(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap-java.io.InputStream-) method:

> Returns an input stream for decoding Base64 encoded byte stream.
>
> The read methods of the returned InputStream will throw IOException when reading bytes that cannot be decoded.
>
> Closing the returned input stream will close the underlying input stream.

The problem with your example code is that it's incomplete and we don't know from where you are getting the `char` value. If you are getting the `char` value from `InputStream` you have the work cut out for `wrap()`.

You can hope to decrease the overall memory requirements by switching from `Base64.getDecorder().decode(String)` to `Base64.getDecorder().decode(byte[])` but if you want to save the heap memory you should rewrite your code to use `InputStream` and don't create temporary `String` or `byte[]`.

Comment: I've just edited the question and added from where the Base64 is coming to SAX parser. When the value tag is active I am using the characters method of SAX parser as you already mentioned it would be better to use InputStream, however, I have some problems implementing this. In detail, I do not know how to add char arrays coming from SAX to one InputStream on the characters method. Additionally when I will use later the Base64.getDecorder().wrap(InputStream) I will get InputStream, not byte[] which I can add to OutputStream with my file. Thank you for some advice so far.